# Local Node.js server consistently fails to connect to AWS RDS database

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I have setup a RDS instance on my AWS account with the following configuration:

```
Engine: MySQL Community
Class: db.t3.small
Region: us-east-2b
```

Sometimes for testing I need to connect to the DB from my local node application which I am running from India. I am using Sequelize as my ORM. Before accessing my DB I make sure my IP is whitelisted in the RDS security group so my local server can access the db.

However in first few attempts I always keep getting the following error:

```
(node:7768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Projects\my-app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Projects\my-app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7768) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My sequelize db configuration looks like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    logging: false
});
```

The thing is after couple of attempts (say 3-4) of restarting the server it finally connects, only to do the same thing when the server is restarted (when I make any changes). Its frustrating to keep doing this and takes me a long time to test something small locally.

Any idea on why this might be happening? Is it my instance class (since its t3 small) or something in my sequelize configuration? I understand that I am accessing a database server setup in the north american continent all the way from asia but it shouldn't be this bad that I have keep restarting and trying many times to finally be able to connect to it.

Any suggestions to mitigate the problem will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you connecting a db in us region from asia region? the network latency can be an issue of unstable app<->db connectivity and you surely don't want to do this in production, even in dev environment thats not desirable as it will affect your debugging speed. Try using all the same config and use a EC2 in us region (same region as your db) , and see if things work first.

Comment: The EC2 is in the same region as the RDS but I am not :( and hence when I try to connect to it locally it just does the above mentioned things. Was wondering if there is a way out of this.